# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibhello_kt (поиск не помог)

Tags: c, компиляция

Собственно собрал разделяемую библиотеку

```
# whereis libhellokt.so
libhellokt: /root/simpleExtension/libhellokt.so

# ls -l /root/simpleExtension/libhellokt.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 427992 Jun 27 13:02 /root/simpleExtension/libhellokt.so
```

*контекст - хочу подключать ее в расширении PHP. Строка компиляции генерируется автоматом*

Сборка отваливается на этапе

```
# cc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/hello.o -L/root/simpleExtension -llibhellokt  -O2 -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/root/simpleExtension   -Wl,-soname -Wl,hello.so -o .libs/hello.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibhello_kt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Т.е. ключи присутствуют

```
-L/root/simpleExtension -llibhellokt
```

Переменные

```
# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
:./:/root/simpleExtension
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:.:/root/simpleExtension
```

Почему он ее не находит? Где косяк?

*UPD*
Сделал симлинк в папку с системными либами - не помогло (ldconfig запускал)

```
# ls -l /usr/lib64/libhellokt.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Jun 27 14:07 /usr/lib64/libhellokt.so -> /root/simpleExtension/libhellokt.so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запустил с ключом `--verbose`, падает на

```
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/collect2 --build-id --no-add-needed --eh-frame-hdr --hash-style=gnu -m elf_x86_64 -shared -o .libs/hello.so /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtbeginS.o -L/root/simpleExtension -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L. -L/root/simpleExtension -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../.. .libs/hello.o -llibhellokt -rpath /root/simpleExtension -soname hello.so -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crtn.o --verbose
```

Запустил с ключом `--verbose`, увидел следующее:

```
attempt to open /root/simpleExtension/liblibhellokt.so failed
attempt to open /root/simpleExtension/liblibhellokt.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/liblibhellokt.so failed
...
```

Т.е. если библиотека компилируется в `libSomeName.so`, то указывать ее надо как `SomeName`, БЕЗ префикса `lib` (и БЕЗ суффикса `.so`)

Comment: проблема решена? ЗЫ: если что, то можно указывать ещё полный путь..

Comment: @Fat-Zer да, решена. Полный путь где? С ключем `-l` пробовал - не помогло

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте не `-llibhellokt` а `-lhellokt`